# Segment by User ID into Different Groups

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js

I'm sure I'm overthinking this, so I'm looking for advice on the best way(s) to segment users based on their authenticated ID (user_id).  Each user of our site is required to login to view any content.  I've enabled the User-ID feature on the property and added a new view.  Each user falls into one of three different user types (all of which I know ahead of time).  The easiest way I can see to analyze each user type is by creating a segment for each group based on their ID.  I need to be able to analyze each of the segments independently and as a part of the whole site's usage, so I thought a segment would work best.  I am able to manipulate each user_id, so I thought I could append an extra bit to the user_id (suffix, perhaps) to help GA identify it as belonging to a specific segment.  What do you all think and do you have any advice on the best way to set this up in GA?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set this custom variable on your site you can use:

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',
    1,                  // Index.  Required parameter.
    'User Category',    // Name.  Required parameter.
    '<user_category>',  // This value of the custom variable.  Required parameter.
    1                   // Sets the scope to visitor-level.  Optional parameter.
]);
```

Use this custom variable in GA to create segments for each group.